# Following a pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

I will show the entire code, but look for the quotes above the pointers as I will be talking about my problem there. I will tell you what I think happened there at the quote comments. The code compiles and runs, I just need help understanding parts of the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int *get_data(int num_grades);
float calc_average(int num_grades, int grades[]);
void display_average(float ave);

int main()
{
        int num_grades = 10;
        const int MAX_GRADE = 100;
```

> Below this quote box at: **int *result = get_data(num_grades);**
>
> I have a pretty simple understanding of pointers at this point, as I've been introduced to them recently, however I can't seem to wrap my head around what happens when you assign a function to a pointer. What I think should happen is that the pointer **int *result** should be pointing at an address. Instead its pointing to a function that is also a pointer i think. So is this a pointer to a pointer at: **int *result = get_data(num_grades);** ?
>
> I will put the rest of my question at the get_data function below.

```
        int *result = get_data(num_grades);
```

> **^ Above ^**

```
        if (num_grades ==0)
                printf("no grades to average\n");
        else
        {
                float ave = calc_average(num_grades, result);
                display_average(ave);
        }

        free(result);
        return 0;
}

float calc_average(int num_grades, int grades[])
{
        float ave;
        int i;
        int sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < num_grades; i++)
        {
                sum+=grades[i];
        }
        ave = (float)sum/num_grades;
        return ave;
}

void display_average(float ave)
{
        printf("average: %.2f\n", ave);
}
```

> Below this quote box,
>
> I think this is a function pointer that returns a int pointer?
>
> So, inside the body of the function, we create a new pointer, allocate memory for it, assign grades for each 'pointee' i think, and then I'm not sure why a[i] = grade is working, what are these indexes coming from, I don't understand why this is working if there is no array declared. Can someone explain what is happening here? How does this work? I'm really confused here.

```
int *get_data(int num_grades)
{

int* a;
a = malloc(num_grades * sizeof(int));
int i;
for (i = 0; i < num_grades; i++)
{
        printf("enter a grade: ");
        int grade;
        scanf("%d", &grade);
        if(grade<=100)
        {
                a[i] = grade;
        }
        else
        {
                printf("grade needs to be > 0 and <= 100\n");
                i--;
        }
}
return a;
```

> **^ Above, this whole function ^**

```
}
```

Comment: `int *result = get_data(num_grades);` This calls the `get_data` function with a single parameter (`num_grades`) and stores the return value in a newly-defined variable called `results` whose type is `int*`.

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating by pulling in pointers to function, but I can imagine you have been introduced to so many concepts and you are trying to make some sense out of what you have been told. I understand your confusion.

Comment: please indent consistently.  suggest after every opening brace '{' indent 4 spaces.  Before every closing brace '}' in-indent.  Never use tabs for indenting.  Because every environment has the tab width and/or tab stops indented differently

Comment: the code does not compile cleanly.  The main function contains the unused constant 'MAX_GRADE'   There are many 'magic' numbers in the code.  Suggest #define those numbers, with meaningful names, then use those meaningful names in the body of the code

Comment: when calling the system function malloc() (and family of functions) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: when calling the system function scanf() and family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameters) to assure the input/conversion operation was successful

Comment: there is a logic error,  When 'int *result' is set from the call to get_data(), then it is too late to check if num_grades is 0.   BTW: get_data() cannot modify the value in num_grades,  So num_grades will always be 10 at the point where it is being checked for 0.  Suggest removing the if, printf, else, { and associated } as the code should always call calc_average() and display_average()

Comment: it seems to me, that a grade of 0, as when student failed to take the associated test, would be a valid value.

Answer (score 3):

`get_data` is a function which returns a pointer to an integer. First of all:

```
int *result = get_data(num_grades);
```

in this line you are not assigning to `result` a pointer to function, but the *result* of the function being called with `num_grades` as argument. That is to say, to the `a` you calculated in the body of `get_data`. And after that:

```
int *get_data(int num_grades)
```

this is the declaration of a function called `get_data` which takes one `int` parameter and returns a pointer to `int`. You could rearrange the spaces like this:

```
int* get_data(int num_grades)
```

if it makes things clearer. In this context, saying that `get_data` is a pointer to function would not even make sense, since it's immediately followed by its body. For reference:

```
int (*get_data)(int num_grades);
```

this is how the declaration of a pointer to function taking one `int` param and returning an `int` looks like. And there can't be a function body after it.

Answer (score 2):

> ... however I can't seem to wrap my head around what happens when you assign a function to a pointer.

You aren't assigning a function to a pointer; you're assigning *the return value* of the function (which happens to be an `int *` value) to a variable which happens to store `int *` values.

> So is this a pointer to a pointer at: `int *result = get_data(num_grades);` ?

No. `int *` means 'pointer to `int`'.

> I think this is a function pointer that returns a int pointer?

No. The function returns an `int *` (pointer to `int`). There is a *function pointer* in your code, though that isn't a *function* (because it's a *function pointer*) and it doesn't *return* anything (because it's *not a function*; it's a *function pointer*).

Remember, `int *` means 'pointer to `int`'.

> and then I'm not sure why a[i] = grade is working, what are these indexes coming from, I don't understand why this is working if there is no array declared. Can someone explain what is happening here? How does this work? I'm really confused here.

The `array[index]` operator is actually a `pointer[index]` operator. It's syntactic sugar for `*(array + index)` or `*(pointer + index)`.

Whenever an expression that has an array type is used (with the exception being taking the `sizeof` or `&addressof` an array), the expression is converted to a pointer. The pointer points to the first item of the array...

So whilst your pointer declaration will have different semantics for the `sizeof` and `&addressof` operators, it'll have the same semantics for the 'array subscript' operator.

A similar concept applies to functions (hence the "function pointer" explanation above). Technically, in your expression `int *result = get_data(num_grades);` you're not applying the `function(argument)` operator; you're applying the `function_pointer(argument)` operator. The expression denoting the function is converted to a function pointer...

Comment: To the quote _this is a function pointer that returns an int pointer_, you say _Yes_.  I'm not completely happy with that.  If the quote was _this is a function that returns an int pointer_, I'd be 100% on board with Yes.  This is a function definition; it really isn't a pointer to a function but it is a function.  In many other contexts, you could get away with 'the name `get_data` is a pointer to a function', but I'm not convinced this is one of them.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeh, I misread that... My bad. Would you be so kind as to have a read through the entire thing again and let me know what you think now?